# rails link_to question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, link-to

I would like to put a <%= link_to ... %> in my layouts/application.html.erb page that links to a page at layouts/post.html.erb. This is clearly very simple but I've been struggling with it all morning. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be fairly easy to do like this:

```
<%= link_to "Link", layouts_path, :method => :post %>
```